# Как нарисовать градиент на canvas?

Tags: color, canvas, javascript

Написал colorpicker, практически без изображений используется только одно, для построения шкалы Hue используется canvas, так вот и последнее изображение хочу заменить на canvas, но не получаться вот изображение

[image]

Оно состоит из 3х частей:

- left - top - белый цвет
- потом по левой стороне идет переход от белого к серому и от серого к черному.
- bottom - черный цвет

и все что справа - прозрачное. Вот похожая реализация только там картинка: [www.colorpicker.com](http://www.colorpicker.com).

Помогите, пожалуста

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawShape(){

  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

  if (canvas.getContext){

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var lingrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,400);

    lingrad.addColorStop(0, "#ededed" );
    lingrad.addColorStop(0.5, "#818181" );
    lingrad.addColorStop(1, "#000000" );
    ctx.fillStyle = lingrad;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  } else {
    alert('You need Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this demo.');
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="drawShape();">
   <canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```